# What is the operand in ls -LA do?

Tags: linux

As the title says what does -LA do in a ls command?

I tried reading the manual for ls and this what it said:

```
 -A      List all entries except for . and ...  Always set for the super-user.

    -L      Follow all symbolic links to final target and list the file or directory the link references rather than the link itself.  This option cancels the -P
             option.
```

But I'm not quite sure what those mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `ls` command prints a list of files and folders in the current directory.

When using `ls -A`, the command prints out ALL files and folders in the current directory. This includes hidden files and folders (like files/folders starting witch a dot). However, `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory) will be ignored.

When using `ls -L` the command will follow symbolic links and print out the location of the reference too.

When combining this 2 options you get `ls -LA` which prints out a list of ALL files and folders, and also prints out the references to symbolic links in the folder.

Just try it out in the terminal. You'll see the difference.

Comment: Are you sure that -A includes the hidden files? It says in the manual that it doesn't.

Comment: i'm quite sure. I'm on windows, but in Git bash it works this way. Capital A will list hidden files, but ignores the implied `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory)

Comment: Edit your answer with **capital** letters (ls -LA). `ls -a` lists even names starting with dot; `ls -A` lists even names starting with dot, _apart_ from ":" and "..".